# Selenium: Go URL's "up"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

is there a way to go urls endings up? For an example :
driver.get("Example.com/1") then driver.get("Example.com/2") then driver.get("Example.com/3") and again and again.
Until it is at 69.

I tried googling, but I didn't found anything.

Comment: There must be a specific reason to go to 69.

Comment: I wanted give an example, and because the site where I want to scrape has 69 search pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just use range for that:

```py
for i in range(1, 70):
    driver.get(f'example/{i}')
    # Do what you want
    driver.quit()
```